# Selecting all <td> elements using javascript and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to select all `<td>` elements that were created through Javascript and add a click event to them. In my code, I added the click event listener to all td's at the bottom of the fillTable() function after creating the td elements, however I am receiving an error stating "addEventListener is not a function." Why is this not working?

I have also tried

```
getElementsByTagName("td").addEventListener("click", clickEvent);
```

but that did not work either. I made sure to include it after the dom loaded, so I think it is the way I am selecting the elements. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

```js
let categories = [];
let catsAndClues = [];

// create Jeopardy Title and Start/Reset button
$("body").append(`
    <h1 id="title">JEOPARDY!</h1>
    <div id="button-div">
        <button id="button" data-startBtn="true">Start!</button>
    </div>
    <div id="game-board">
    </div>`)

async function getCategoryIds() {
    // save random number from one to 18000 to randomInt
    // randomInt will be used as the "offset" parameter to get a random sequence of categories
    let randomInt = Math.floor((Math.random() * 18000) + 1);
    let res = await axios.get(`http://jservice.io/api/categories?count=100&offset=${randomInt}`);
    // create a loop to iterate until the categories array contains 6 items
    for (let i=0;categories.length<6;i++){
        // pull random ID number from the 100 categories pulled from API
        let i= Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
        let randomCatId= res.data[i].id;
        // if categories array does not include the randomCatId, add it to the categories array
        if (!categories.includes(randomCatId)){
            categories.push(randomCatId);
        }
        console.log(categories);
    }
}


async function getCategory(catId) {
    // retreive clues from API with the category ID parameter
    let res = await axios.get(`http://jservice.io/api/clues?category=${catId}`);
    // use .map function to return object displaying question, answer, and "showing"
    // properties for every item in the data's array
    let clueGroup = res.data.map(clue => {
        return {
          question: clue.question,
          answer: clue.answer,
          showing: null,
        };
    })
    console.log("clueGroup:", clueGroup);
    let clueArray = [];
    for (let i=0;clueArray.length<5;i++){
        // pull random clue from the clues array and save to variable
        let i= Math.floor((Math.random() * clueGroup.length));
        let randomClue= clueGroup[i];
        // if categories array does not include the randomCatId, add it to the categories array
        if (!clueArray.includes(randomClue)){
            clueArray.push(randomClue);
        }
    };
    // define obj to show category title and list of all clues within the category
    console.log("clueArray: ", clueArray);
    console.log(res.data[0].category.title);
    return {title: res.data[0].category.title, clues: clueArray};
}

function fillTable() {
    $("#game-board").append(
        `<table id="table">
        <thead>
            <tr id="header-row">
                <th>${catsAndClues[0].title}</th>
                <th>${catsAndClues[1].title}</th>
                <th>${catsAndClues[2].title}</th>
                <th>${catsAndClues[3].title}</th>
                <th>${catsAndClues[4].title}</th>
                <th>${catsAndClues[5].title}</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td data-question= "${catsAndClues[0].clues[0].question}" 
                      data-answer= "${catsAndClues[0].clues[0].answer}" 
                     data-showing= "${catsAndClues[0].clues[0].showing}">?
                </td>
                <td data-question= "${catsAndClues[1].clues[0].question}" 
                      data-answer= "${catsAndClues[1].clues[0].answer}" 
                     data-showing= "${catsAndClues[1].clues[0].showing}">?
                </td>
                <td data-question= "${catsAndClues[2].clues[0].question}" 
                      data-answer= "${catsAndClues[2].clues[0].answer}" 
                     data-showing= "${catsAndClues[2].clues[0].showing}">?
                </td>
                <td data-question= "${catsAndClues[3].clues[0].question}" 
                      data-answer= "${catsAndClues[3].clues[0].answer}" 
                     data-showing= "${catsAndClues[3].clues[0].showing}">?
                </td>
                <td data-question= "${catsAndClues[4].clues[0].question}" 
                      data-answer= "${catsAndClues[4].clues[0].answer}" 
                     data-showing= "${catsAndClues[4].clues[0].showing}">?
                </td>
                <td data-question= "${catsAndClues[5].clues[0].question}" 
                      data-answer= "${catsAndClues[5].clues[0].answer}" 
                     data-showing= "${catsAndClues[5].clues[0].showing}">?
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td data-question= "${catsAndClues[0].clues[1].question}" 
                      data-answer= "${catsAndClues[0].clues[1].answer}" 
                     data-showing= "${catsAndClues[0].clues[1].showing}">?
                </td>
                <td data-question= "${catsAndClues[1].clues[1].question}" 
                      data-answer= "${catsAndClues[1].clues[1].answer}" 
                     data-showing= "${catsAndClues[1].clues[1].showing}">?
                </td>
                <td data-question= "${catsAndClues[2].clues[1].question}" 
                      data-answer= "${catsAndClues[2].clues[1].answer}" 
                     data-showing= "${catsAndClues[2].clues[1].showing}">?
                </td>
                <td data-question= "${catsAndClues[3].clues[1].question}" 
                      data-answer= "${catsAndClues[3].clues[1].answer}" 
                     data-showing= "${catsAndClues[3].clues[1].showing}">?
                </td>
                <td data-question= "${catsAndClues[4].clues[1].question}" 
                      data-answer= "${catsAndClues[4].clues[1].answer}" 
                     data-showing= "${catsAndClues[4].clues[1].showing}">?
                </td>
                <td data-question= "${catsAndClues[5].clues[1].question}" 
                      data-answer= "${catsAndClues[5].clues[1].answer}" 
                     data-showing= "${catsAndClues[5].clues[1].showing}">?
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td data-question= "${catsAndClues[0].clues[2].question}" 
                      data-answer= "${catsAndClues[0].clues[2].answer}" 
                     data-showing= "${catsAndClues[0].clues[2].showing}">?
                </td>
                <td data-question= "${catsAndClues[1].clues[2].question}" 
                      data-answer= "${catsAndClues[1].clues[2].answer}" 
                     data-showing= "${catsAndClues[1].clues[2].showing}">?
                </td>
                <td data-question= "${catsAndClues[2].clues[2].question}" 
                      data-answer= "${catsAndClues[2].clues[2].answer}" 
                     data-showing= "${catsAndClues[2].clues[2].showing}">?
                </td>
                <td data-question= "${catsAndClues[3].clues[2].question}" 
                      data-answer= "${catsAndClues[3].clues[2].answer}" 
                     data-showing= "${catsAndClues[3].clues[2].showing}">?
                </td>
                <td data-question= "${catsAndClues[4].clues[2].question}" 
                      data-answer= "${catsAndClues[4].clues[2].answer}" 
                     data-showing= "${catsAndClues[4].clues[2].showing}">?
                </td>
                <td data-question= "${catsAndClues[5].clues[2].question}" 
                      data-answer= "${catsAndClues[5].clues[2].answer}" 
                     data-showing= "${catsAndClues[5].clues[2].showing}">?
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td data-question= "${catsAndClues[0].clues[3].question}" 
                      data-answer= "${catsAndClues[0].clues[3].answer}" 
                     data-showing= "${catsAndClues[0].clues[3].showing}">?
                </td>
                <td data-question= "${catsAndClues[1].clues[3].question}" 
                      data-answer= "${catsAndClues[1].clues[3].answer}" 
                     data-showing= "${catsAndClues[1].clues[3].showing}">?
                </td>
                <td data-question= "${catsAndClues[2].clues[3].question}" 
                      data-answer= "${catsAndClues[2].clues[3].answer}" 
                     data-showing= "${catsAndClues[2].clues[3].showing}">?
                </td>
                <td data-question= "${catsAndClues[3].clues[3].question}" 
                      data-answer= "${catsAndClues[3].clues[3].answer}" 
                     data-showing= "${catsAndClues[3].clues[3].showing}">?
                </td>
                <td data-question= "${catsAndClues[4].clues[3].question}" 
                      data-answer= "${catsAndClues[4].clues[3].answer}" 
                     data-showing= "${catsAndClues[4].clues[3].showing}">?
                </td>
                <td data-question= "${catsAndClues[5].clues[3].question}" 
                      data-answer= "${catsAndClues[5].clues[3].answer}" 
                     data-showing= "${catsAndClues[5].clues[3].showing}">?
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td data-question= "${catsAndClues[0].clues[4].question}" 
                      data-answer= "${catsAndClues[0].clues[4].answer}" 
                     data-showing= "${catsAndClues[0].clues[4].showing}">?
                </td>
                <td data-question= "${catsAndClues[1].clues[4].question}" 
                      data-answer= "${catsAndClues[1].clues[4].answer}" 
                     data-showing= "${catsAndClues[1].clues[4].showing}">?
                </td>
                <td data-question= "${catsAndClues[2].clues[4].question}" 
                      data-answer= "${catsAndClues[2].clues[4].answer}" 
                     data-showing= "${catsAndClues[2].clues[4].showing}">?
                </td>
                <td data-question= "${catsAndClues[3].clues[4].question}" 
                      data-answer= "${catsAndClues[3].clues[4].answer}" 
                     data-showing= "${catsAndClues[3].clues[4].showing}">?
                </td>
                <td data-question= "${catsAndClues[4].clues[4].question}" 
                      data-answer= "${catsAndClues[4].clues[4].answer}" 
                     data-showing= "${catsAndClues[4].clues[4].showing}">?
                </td>
                <td data-question= "${catsAndClues[5].clues[4].question}" 
                      data-answer= "${catsAndClues[5].clues[4].answer}" 
                     data-showing= "${catsAndClues[5].clues[4].showing}">?
                </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>`);
        $("td").addEventListener("click", clickEvent);
}
// document.addEventListener("click", function(e){console.dir(e.target);});
// document.addEventListener("click", function(e){console.dir(e.target.dataset.question);});
// document.addEventListener("click", function(e){console.dir(e.target.dataset.answer);});
// document.addEventListener("click", function(e){console.dir(e.target.dataset.showing);});
/** Handle clicking on a clue: show the question or answer.
 *
 * Uses .showing property on clue to determine what to show:
 * - if currently null, show question & set .showing to "question"
 * - if currently "question", show answer & set .showing to "answer"
 * - if currently "answer", ignore click
 * */



function clickEvent(e) {
    let tile = e.target;
    let question = tile.dataset.question;
    let answer = tile.dataset.answer;
    let showing = tile.dataset.showing;
    console.log(question, answer, showing);
    // if (tile.showing == "answer"){
    //     return};

    // if (!showing){
    //     tile.innerHTML = question;
    //     showing = "question"
    // }
    // else if (showing == question){
    //     tile.innerHTML = answer;
    //     showing = "answer"
    // }
    // else {return}
}



async function setupAndStart() {
    await getCategoryIds();
    console.log(catsAndClues);
    for (let i=0;catsAndClues.length<6;i++){
        let tempVar = await getCategory(categories[i]);
        catsAndClues[i] = tempVar;
    }
    console.log(catsAndClues);
    fillTable();

}
setupAndStart()
```

```css
/* some colors you may find useful:
  #115ff4
  #060ce9
  #28a200
  #8d2ab5
  #74119c
*/

body {
  background-color: black;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#title {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 4px 4px black;
  font-size: 5em;
  margin: 5px 5px 15px 5px;
}

#button-div{
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}

#button{
  padding: 5px 20px 5px 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

table {
  margin-left:auto; 
  margin-right:auto;
  background-color: black; 
}

th {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border: 3px solid black;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #060ce9;
}

td {
  text-align: center;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: .5em;
  background-color: #060ce9;
}


table, td {
  border: 3px solid black;
}

#header-row {
  color: white;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 1em;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport"
        content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title></title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Copse&display=swap"
        rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="jeopardy.css">
</head>
<body>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/jquery"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/lodash"></script>
<script src="jeopardy.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use `$("td").on("click", clickEvent)` Instead of `$("td").addEventListener("click", clickEvent)`

Comment: Yup! This works. I remember learning about .on() and don't know how I forgot about it. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way of achieving the same result would be to apply a "delegated event listening" with `.on()` on the parent table:

```
$('#table').on('click','td', function(ev){...})
```

You can do this even *before* you fill the table, as it *delegates* the click event from the table to every current and future `<TD>` inside.

Answer (score 1):

@Bolmstead, try `on` instead of `addEventListener`

```
$("td").addEventListener("click", clickEvent);
```

```js
let categories = [];
let catsAndClues = [];

// create Jeopardy Title and Start/Reset button
$("body").append(`
    <h1 id="title">JEOPARDY!</h1>
    <div id="button-div">
        <button id="button" data-startBtn="true">Start!</button>
    </div>
    <div id="game-board">
    </div>`)

async function getCategoryIds() {
    // save random number from one to 18000 to randomInt
    // randomInt will be used as the "offset" parameter to get a random sequence of categories
    let randomInt = Math.floor((Math.random() * 18000) + 1);
    let res = await axios.get(`http://jservice.io/api/categories?count=100&offset=${randomInt}`);
    // create a loop to iterate until the categories array contains 6 items
    for (let i=0;categories.length<6;i++){
        // pull random ID number from the 100 categories pulled from API
        let i= Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
        let randomCatId= res.data[i].id;
        // if categories array does not include the randomCatId, add it to the categories array
        if (!categories.includes(randomCatId)){
            categories.push(randomCatId);
        }
        console.log(categories);
    }
}


async function getCategory(catId) {
    // retreive clues from API with the category ID parameter
    let res = await axios.get(`http://jservice.io/api/clues?category=${catId}`);
    // use .map function to return object displaying question, answer, and "showing"
    // properties for every item in the data's array
    let clueGroup = res.data.map(clue => {
        return {
          question: clue.question,
          answer: clue.answer,
          showing: null,
        };
    })
    console.log("clueGroup:", clueGroup);
    let clueArray = [];
    for (let i=0;clueArray.length<5;i++){
        // pull random clue from the clues array and save to variable
        let i= Math.floor((Math.random() * clueGroup.length));
        let randomClue= clueGroup[i];
        // if categories array does not include the randomCatId, add it to the categories array
        if (!clueArray.includes(randomClue)){
            clueArray.push(randomClue);
        }
    };
    // define obj to show category title and list of all clues within the category
    console.log("clueArray: ", clueArray);
    console.log(res.data[0].category.title);
    return {title: res.data[0].category.title, clues: clueArray};
}

function fillTable() {
    $("#game-board").append(
        `<table id="table">
        <thead>
            <tr id="header-row">
                <th>${catsAndClues[0].title}</th>
                <th>${catsAndClues[1].title}</th>
                <th>${catsAndClues[2].title}</th>
                <th>${catsAndClues[3].title}</th>
                <th>${catsAndClues[4].title}</th>
                <th>${catsAndClues[5].title}</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td data-question= "${catsAndClues[0].clues[0].question}" 
                      data-answer= "${catsAndClues[0].clues[0].answer}" 
                     data-showing= "${catsAndClues[0].clues[0].showing}">?
                </td>
                <td data-question= "${catsAndClues[1].clues[0].question}" 
                      data-answer= "${catsAndClues[1].clues[0].answer}" 
                     data-showing= "${catsAndClues[1].clues[0].showing}">?
                </td>
                <td data-question= "${catsAndClues[2].clues[0].question}" 
                      data-answer= "${catsAndClues[2].clues[0].answer}" 
                     data-showing= "${catsAndClues[2].clues[0].showing}">?
                </td>
                <td data-question= "${catsAndClues[3].clues[0].question}" 
                      data-answer= "${catsAndClues[3].clues[0].answer}" 
                     data-showing= "${catsAndClues[3].clues[0].showing}">?
                </td>
                <td data-question= "${catsAndClues[4].clues[0].question}" 
                      data-answer= "${catsAndClues[4].clues[0].answer}" 
                     data-showing= "${catsAndClues[4].clues[0].showing}">?
                </td>
                <td data-question= "${catsAndClues[5].clues[0].question}" 
                      data-answer= "${catsAndClues[5].clues[0].answer}" 
                     data-showing= "${catsAndClues[5].clues[0].showing}">?
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td data-question= "${catsAndClues[0].clues[1].question}" 
                      data-answer= "${catsAndClues[0].clues[1].answer}" 
                     data-showing= "${catsAndClues[0].clues[1].showing}">?
                </td>
                <td data-question= "${catsAndClues[1].clues[1].question}" 
                      data-answer= "${catsAndClues[1].clues[1].answer}" 
                     data-showing= "${catsAndClues[1].clues[1].showing}">?
                </td>
                <td data-question= "${catsAndClues[2].clues[1].question}" 
                      data-answer= "${catsAndClues[2].clues[1].answer}" 
                     data-showing= "${catsAndClues[2].clues[1].showing}">?
                </td>
                <td data-question= "${catsAndClues[3].clues[1].question}" 
                      data-answer= "${catsAndClues[3].clues[1].answer}" 
                     data-showing= "${catsAndClues[3].clues[1].showing}">?
                </td>
                <td data-question= "${catsAndClues[4].clues[1].question}" 
                      data-answer= "${catsAndClues[4].clues[1].answer}" 
                     data-showing= "${catsAndClues[4].clues[1].showing}">?
                </td>
                <td data-question= "${catsAndClues[5].clues[1].question}" 
                      data-answer= "${catsAndClues[5].clues[1].answer}" 
                     data-showing= "${catsAndClues[5].clues[1].showing}">?
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td data-question= "${catsAndClues[0].clues[2].question}" 
                      data-answer= "${catsAndClues[0].clues[2].answer}" 
                     data-showing= "${catsAndClues[0].clues[2].showing}">?
                </td>
                <td data-question= "${catsAndClues[1].clues[2].question}" 
                      data-answer= "${catsAndClues[1].clues[2].answer}" 
                     data-showing= "${catsAndClues[1].clues[2].showing}">?
                </td>
                <td data-question= "${catsAndClues[2].clues[2].question}" 
                      data-answer= "${catsAndClues[2].clues[2].answer}" 
                     data-showing= "${catsAndClues[2].clues[2].showing}">?
                </td>
                <td data-question= "${catsAndClues[3].clues[2].question}" 
                      data-answer= "${catsAndClues[3].clues[2].answer}" 
                     data-showing= "${catsAndClues[3].clues[2].showing}">?
                </td>
                <td data-question= "${catsAndClues[4].clues[2].question}" 
                      data-answer= "${catsAndClues[4].clues[2].answer}" 
                     data-showing= "${catsAndClues[4].clues[2].showing}">?
                </td>
                <td data-question= "${catsAndClues[5].clues[2].question}" 
                      data-answer= "${catsAndClues[5].clues[2].answer}" 
                     data-showing= "${catsAndClues[5].clues[2].showing}">?
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td data-question= "${catsAndClues[0].clues[3].question}" 
                      data-answer= "${catsAndClues[0].clues[3].answer}" 
                     data-showing= "${catsAndClues[0].clues[3].showing}">?
                </td>
                <td data-question= "${catsAndClues[1].clues[3].question}" 
                      data-answer= "${catsAndClues[1].clues[3].answer}" 
                     data-showing= "${catsAndClues[1].clues[3].showing}">?
                </td>
                <td data-question= "${catsAndClues[2].clues[3].question}" 
                      data-answer= "${catsAndClues[2].clues[3].answer}" 
                     data-showing= "${catsAndClues[2].clues[3].showing}">?
                </td>
                <td data-question= "${catsAndClues[3].clues[3].question}" 
                      data-answer= "${catsAndClues[3].clues[3].answer}" 
                     data-showing= "${catsAndClues[3].clues[3].showing}">?
                </td>
                <td data-question= "${catsAndClues[4].clues[3].question}" 
                      data-answer= "${catsAndClues[4].clues[3].answer}" 
                     data-showing= "${catsAndClues[4].clues[3].showing}">?
                </td>
                <td data-question= "${catsAndClues[5].clues[3].question}" 
                      data-answer= "${catsAndClues[5].clues[3].answer}" 
                     data-showing= "${catsAndClues[5].clues[3].showing}">?
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td data-question= "${catsAndClues[0].clues[4].question}" 
                      data-answer= "${catsAndClues[0].clues[4].answer}" 
                     data-showing= "${catsAndClues[0].clues[4].showing}">?
                </td>
                <td data-question= "${catsAndClues[1].clues[4].question}" 
                      data-answer= "${catsAndClues[1].clues[4].answer}" 
                     data-showing= "${catsAndClues[1].clues[4].showing}">?
                </td>
                <td data-question= "${catsAndClues[2].clues[4].question}" 
                      data-answer= "${catsAndClues[2].clues[4].answer}" 
                     data-showing= "${catsAndClues[2].clues[4].showing}">?
                </td>
                <td data-question= "${catsAndClues[3].clues[4].question}" 
                      data-answer= "${catsAndClues[3].clues[4].answer}" 
                     data-showing= "${catsAndClues[3].clues[4].showing}">?
                </td>
                <td data-question= "${catsAndClues[4].clues[4].question}" 
                      data-answer= "${catsAndClues[4].clues[4].answer}" 
                     data-showing= "${catsAndClues[4].clues[4].showing}">?
                </td>
                <td data-question= "${catsAndClues[5].clues[4].question}" 
                      data-answer= "${catsAndClues[5].clues[4].answer}" 
                     data-showing= "${catsAndClues[5].clues[4].showing}">?
                </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>`);
        $("td").on("click", clickEvent);
}
// document.addEventListener("click", function(e){console.dir(e.target);});
// document.addEventListener("click", function(e){console.dir(e.target.dataset.question);});
// document.addEventListener("click", function(e){console.dir(e.target.dataset.answer);});
// document.addEventListener("click", function(e){console.dir(e.target.dataset.showing);});
/** Handle clicking on a clue: show the question or answer.
 *
 * Uses .showing property on clue to determine what to show:
 * - if currently null, show question & set .showing to "question"
 * - if currently "question", show answer & set .showing to "answer"
 * - if currently "answer", ignore click
 * */



function clickEvent(e) {
    let tile = e.target;
    let question = tile.dataset.question;
    let answer = tile.dataset.answer;
    let showing = tile.dataset.showing;
    console.log(question, answer, showing);
    // if (tile.showing == "answer"){
    //     return};

    // if (!showing){
    //     tile.innerHTML = question;
    //     showing = "question"
    // }
    // else if (showing == question){
    //     tile.innerHTML = answer;
    //     showing = "answer"
    // }
    // else {return}
}



async function setupAndStart() {
    await getCategoryIds();
    console.log(catsAndClues);
    for (let i=0;catsAndClues.length<6;i++){
        let tempVar = await getCategory(categories[i]);
        catsAndClues[i] = tempVar;
    }
    console.log(catsAndClues);
    fillTable();

}
setupAndStart()
```

```css
/* some colors you may find useful:
  #115ff4
  #060ce9
  #28a200
  #8d2ab5
  #74119c
*/

body {
  background-color: black;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#title {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 4px 4px black;
  font-size: 5em;
  margin: 5px 5px 15px 5px;
}

#button-div{
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}

#button{
  padding: 5px 20px 5px 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

table {
  margin-left:auto; 
  margin-right:auto;
  background-color: black; 
}

th {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border: 3px solid black;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #060ce9;
}

td {
  text-align: center;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: .5em;
  background-color: #060ce9;
}


table, td {
  border: 3px solid black;
}

#header-row {
  color: white;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 1em;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport"
        content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title></title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Copse&display=swap"
        rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="jeopardy.css">
</head>
<body>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/jquery"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/lodash"></script>
<script src="jeopardy.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```